# Orientation implementation issue Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I use storyboard and have lot of viewcontroller. I'm facing issue on Orientation. I have tried different ways which has provided stackoverflow. But i did't get any answer. Is there any issue on Xcode 6.0 with ios 8?

My implementation process:

step 1:  [image]

I have added below code in Newscontroller.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)self{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Now question is ... i need disable orientation specific view controllers like keep only portrait. Any one having idea?

Answer (score 0):

My test and works:

In your specific viewcontroller, only this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Cut off shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow? Here works fine. I did an edition

Comment: Thank you so much... But i'm using REFrostedViewController side menu lib...might be issue on library ...... i have tested sample example. it's working

Answer (score 0):

1) Set

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

2) Add

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

That's it :)